# Injective or surjective linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be an arbitrary linear transformation. Does an $f$ exist, which is injective/surjective.

I feel like the answer to both should be yes, because although the matrix $A$ corresponding to that transformation is not a square, we only need to find a matrix $A^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 x 4}$ that is the left-inverse of $A$. Surjectivity would be ensured that way, because given a vector $w$, we only need to calculate $A^{-1}w$. With injectivity I am not quite sure how to argue my case.

Comment: Why we only need to find a left-inverse of $A$? By the way, this ensures that $A$ is injective, for if $B$ is a left-inverse of $A$, then $Av=0$ implies $v = Iv = (BA)v = B(Av) = 0$.

Comment: For injectivity: Is there any natural map that comes to mind from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^4$? If you wanted to think of $\Bbb R^3$ as "sitting inside" $\Bbb R^4$, what map would you think of?

Comment: Ok, I understand your reasoning for injectivity, but if B was the left-inverse of A, then wouldn't this also show surjectivity, because for every $w \in \mathbb{R}$, we could just calculate $v = Bw$, which would then satisfy $f(v) = w$.

Comment: That $B$ is a left inverse of $A$ means that $BA=I$, but not necessarily $AB=I$.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean, but now I am even more lost as to how to show that $f$ can be surjective.

Comment: I thought about the rank-nullity formula and I think this would prove that no such surjective $f$ can exist. The formula gives us $3 = dim ker f + dim im f$. For it to be surjective $dim im f$ would need to be 4, but then the formula can't hold. Would this be a valid prove?

Comment: @roblox99 That's a perfectly valid proof! Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose such linear transformation can be surjective and try applying the rank-nullity theorem, that should give you a contradiction...